# How to reveal search bar on ListView pull down action in flutter?

Tags: flutter, searchbar, flutter-listview

I want to implement a search bar that is revealed when user performs pull down action in `ListView` and hide it when user scrolls the `ListView` (just like in iOS). But can't find any relevant information on how can one implement this. [This answer wasn't helpful at all](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49494094/12071531) as `RefreshIndicator` only returns a refresh indicator. No code to show as I have no clue how this could be done in Flutter.

**EDIT:**

Code:

```
NestedScrollView(
                  headerSliverBuilder:
                      (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) =>
                          <Widget>[
                    SliverOverlapAbsorber(
                        handle: NestedScrollView.sliverOverlapAbsorberHandleFor(
                            context),
                        sliver: SliverAppBar(
                          collapsedHeight: 100,
                          expandedHeight: 100,
                          toolbarHeight: 100,
                          leadingWidth: 0,
                          leading: Container(),
                          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                          title: TextField(),
                        )),
                  ],
                  body: ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: _itemCount,
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                        return Text('Item $index');
                      }),
                ),
```

Thanks!

Comment: You can use `SliverAppBar()` with some custom designing you can achieve that. Check out full documentation of `SliverAppBar()` https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SliverAppBar-class.html

Comment: @ChiragBargoojar edited my post and added some code, works almost as intended, but any idea how I can hide `SliverAppBar()` by default (do not show it before user has performed the pull down action)?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? If you didn't you can use https://pub.dev/packages/pull_to_reveal 

I need to do the same but for a custom scroll view

Answer (score 0):

I found a nice way to do this using flutter's native material [showSearch](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showSearch.html) function. showSearch + its delegate handles the searching display part, so you have to make do with the material way of doing things going this route (image below)

Then, to do the 'drag' functionality, you can wrap a scrollable widget in this class:

*N.B. Code below is using flutter hooks package, just use a stateful widget to manage isDragFromEdge if you are not using hooks*

```
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:flutter_hooks/flutter_hooks.dart';

// The drag delta needed to trigger the onPull function
const kDragTriggerDelta = 15;

class PullScrollable extends HookWidget {
  final Widget child;
  final Function onPull;

  const PullScrollable({
    Key? key,
    required this.child,
    required this.onPull,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final isDragFromEdge = useState(false);

    // Detects if the drag started from the top of the scrollable
    bool getIsDragFromEdge(ScrollStartNotification notification) {
      return notification.metrics.extentBefore == 0.0 &&
          isDragFromEdge.value == false;
    }

    bool handleDragFromEdge() {
      isDragFromEdge.value = true;

      return false;
    }

    bool handleDragEnd() {
      isDragFromEdge.value = false;

      return false;
    }

    // Detects if the drag is in an upwards motion exceeding the trigger delta
    bool getIsOverscroll(ScrollNotification notification) {
      if (!isDragFromEdge.value) return false;

      if ((notification is ScrollUpdateNotification &&
              (notification.dragDetails?.primaryDelta ?? 0) >
                  kDragTriggerDelta) ||
          (notification is OverscrollNotification &&
              (notification.dragDetails?.primaryDelta ?? 0) >
                  kDragTriggerDelta)) {
        return true;
      }

      return false;
    }

    // On overscroll, trigger the onPull function
    bool handleOverscroll() {
      onPull();

      isDragFromEdge.value = false;

      return false;
    }

    return NotificationListener<ScrollNotification>(
      child: child,
      onNotification: (notification) {
        if (notification is ScrollStartNotification &&
            getIsDragFromEdge(notification)) handleDragFromEdge();

        if (notification is ScrollEndNotification) handleDragEnd();

        if (getIsOverscroll(notification)) handleOverscroll();

        return false;
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Combining the two you have something like

```
class ListView extends StatelessWidget {
  const ListView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return PullScrollable(
      onPull: () {
        showSearch(context: context, delegate: YourDelegate());
      },
      child: ListView(),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]